# Xampp says it's running but is not reachable

Tags: apache2, xampp

Very awkward problem... I don't really know what the title should be ...

I had xampp running, and firefox opened and I started the virtual machine using VirtualBox. Than I had some problem with workspace switcher (i couldn't press esc or windows key and the mouse didn't respond... everything was blocked) so I had to power off the laptop (holding power button for 5 secs).

When I started it again, xampp didn't work any more. I start it using "/opt/lampp/lampp start" normally but I can't reach it from firefox. Just like apache is not running.

I'm using ElementaryOS on a 64 bit Dell Studio laptop and Xampp 1.8.1.

Are there any xampp gurus here?

Comment: All this talk of a virtual machine is confusing. What install is xampp running on? What install is Firefox running on? Does the VM have anything to do with anything apart from being the reason you needed to restart?

Comment: Yes... I only pointed out FF, VBox and Workspace swithcer as reasons why I had to restart..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `/opt/lampp/lampp stop` command I noticed some error:

`AH00058: Error retrieving pid file logs/httpd.pid`

Removing the /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid file and than restarting xampp fixed the problem...